# customize django model meta ordering option

Tags: django, django-models, metaclass

This is how my code looks like

```
class User(AbstractUser,TimeStampModel,Address,TrashBin):

    FirstFormat = "First name Last name"
    SecondFormat = "Last name First name"
    ThirdFormat = "Last name, First name"

    NAME_FORMATS = Choices(
        (FirstFormat, _("First name Last name")),
        (SecondFormat, _("Last name First name")),
        (ThirdFormat, _("Last name, First name")),
    )
    name_format = models.CharField(_("Name Format"),max_length=150,choices=NAME_FORMATS,default="First name Last name")
    

    class Meta:
        ordering = [Case(
            When(name_format= User.FirstFormat, then="'first_name', 'last_name'"),
            When(name_format= User.SecondFormat, then="'last_name','first_name'"),
            When(name_format= User.ThirdFormat, then="'last_name','first_name'"),
            default= '"first_name","last_name"'
        )]
```

Comment: This makes no sense, especially since if you have two items with a different format, how would you compare between these two? Based on the first ordering? The second ordering?

Comment: I have a choice variable if i select the one the ordering has to be changed. If there is any other way to achieve this kind of ordering. let me know